# Jquery Favourites Button for products

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I want to be able to use the jquery click function to send my font awsome icon to the web method my problem is the icon will have mulitple images in the form of iconFavourites_productcode product code being alaphnumeric id that identifys the product code the customer wants to fave.

This is a vb.net application in the asp.net platform.

```
$('i.button').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('fa-heart-o')) {
        $this.removeClass('fa-heart-o');
        $this.addClass('fa-heart');
    } else {
        $this.removeClass('fa-heart');
        $this.addClass('fa-heart-o');
    }
});
```

I no I can use the above to change the icon but all I want to do is change the icon to red when the person has added it to the db and black when its not. I was thinking I would have some kinda of web method like

```
[WebMethod]
Function FaveProduct(productId As String,ActiveState as int)

End Function
```

My Question is how would I using a post send my button click to the webmethod I can use jquery for this but not sure how or what best way to send the active in active state to my function. I was thinking ActiveState  1 added 2 removed. Can anyone tell me how I would code this in jquery post?

I also need to no how sep the id from the name portion of the icon i am using.

Comment: jquery ajax post to your webmethod and do some logic to return value for you to determine what icon should display, try to google or find in stackoverflow of way to call ajax

Comment: I no how to call but the problem is how to account for the product id in the id field how do i seperate it out for the function call

Comment: I not sure what you trying to ask? r you asking how to pass the icon class into the function parameter productId or?

Comment: iF YOU look at my question I ask how to sep the iconame_productCode format so that it goes to my webmethodname(productcode as string) function there will be multiple icons so i had to give them all unqiue name

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by jQuery and CSS directly.
add new class named it fav_color

```
<style>
 .fav_color{
     color:red;
  }
</style>
```

Now Using jQuery add this class.

```
$this.addClass('fav_color');
```

Or remove it

```
$this.removeClass('fav_color');
```

Comment: if you look at my question Yassir its  a we bit more advanced than that what I am asking

Comment: can u explain more your scenario?